# How can I improve code coverage of Python3

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py, python-3.8

With `unittest` and Coverage.py,

```py
def add_one(num: int):
    num = num + 1
    return num
```

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from add_one import add_one


class TestAddOne(TestCase):

    def test_add_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(add_one(0), 1)
        self.assertNotEqual(add_one(0), 2)
```

and here is the coverage:

[image: code coverage 33%]

How can I test the whole file?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your test file is called `test_one.py` run this command in the same directory:

```
coverage run  -m unittest test_one.py && coverage report
```

Result should look similar to this:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Name          Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------
add_one.py        3      0   100%
test_one.py       6      0   100%
---------------------------------
TOTAL             9      0   100%
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call the `test_add_one` method.

Note how the function definition is executed, but not the body. To run your test, add a `__main__` check and a `TestSuite`/`TextTestRunner` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

```py
from unittest import TestCase, TestSuite, TextTestRunner
from add_one import add_one


class TestAddOne(TestCase):

    def test_add_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(add_one(0), 1)
        self.assertNotEqual(add_one(0), 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestAddOne("test_add_one"))

    TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

The result of

```sh
coverage run <file.py>
coverage html
# OR
coverage report -m
```

is all lines tested. [image]

Comment: You no longer need to write these TestSuite stanzas.  Just use "python -m unittest discover"

Comment: Then you wouldn't be able to run `coverage run` and have the tests run. The entry point through the coverage module is `__main__` (though perhaps there is a detail I missed); normally you are entirely correct.